# Modifying a Regex Expression

Tags: python, regex, string, function, conditional-statements

i have several strings to match certain expressions where i want to match and extract 2 words after the prepositions along with the preps themselves.. And they do a good job too . But i need to modify the regex such that in case the word "to" appears after the preposition , The regex will extract the preposition followed by 3 words(instead of default 2 words..)
here's an example to elaborate:

```
str1 = " that place is near oberoi mall"
str2 = " that place is next to oberoi mall"
```

Expected results:-
`res1 = "near oberoi mall"`  #extract 2 words after prep along with it (default case)
`res2 = "next to oberoi mall"` #extract prep along with 3 words after it (in case "to" comes after a preposition)

What have I done?

```
def landmark(str):
    preps = ['near','off','next','across','opposite','behind','above','ahead']
    words = "|".join(re.escape(line.rstrip()) for line in preps)
    p1 = re.compile(r'(?:{})\s(\w+|\d+\w+)\s\w+'.format(words))
    q =re.search(p1,str)
    if q is None:
       return ""
    else:
        return q.group()
```

My preps are in the list called `preps`
This does well in returning 2 words so I get

```
res1 = "near oberoi mall"
```

`res2 = "next to oberoi"` #this becomes incomplete

What did I try?
here:

```
p1 = re.compile(r'(?:{}(?:to)?)\s(\w+|\d+\w+)\s\w+'.format(words))
```

*notice the optional (?:to)? I added for it. there's some small problem.. Please help.

Comment: This might not help you directly, but regex is not the best tool to use for something like this. Have you had a look at [nltk](http://www.nltk.org/). From what I know, it supports similar tokenization out of the box.

Comment: yes i have. my data consists of addresses which arent a part of the English language.. that wont help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for your example:

```
>>> p1 = re.compile(r'(?:%s)\s((?:to\s)?(\w+|\d+\w+)\s\w+)' % words)
>>> dd = re.search(p1,str1)
>>> dd.group()
'near oberoi mall'
>>> cc = re.search(p1,str2)
>>> cc.group()
'next to oberoi mall'
```